# Printing receipt from server to local printer

Tags: php, printing, epson

I am working on one project,my client want thermal printing system.I tried and working well in localhost.When I upload in server it is not working,I add a printer as Generic text plain.Here is my code..

```
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("Receipt Printer");
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> initialize();
$printer -> setJustification( Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER );
$printer -> selectPrintMode( Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH |
    $printer -> text("Order ID : ".$orderid."\n");
    $printer -> text("Employee ID : ".$empid."\n");
    $printer -> text("Dish Name : ".$dishname."\n");
    $printer -> text("thanks for Ordering...\n");
    $printer -> cut();
```

working perfectly in localhost.Please tell me how to connect the printer to work..

```
Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to print. Command "smbclient '//cs1008.webhostbox.net/Receipt Printer' -c 'print -' -N" failed with exit code 127: sh: smbclient: command not found
```

I am getting this error message..I know the problen is the connection..Please tell me what are the way I can solve this..I used qz.io library but it is prompting..please help me..

Answer (score 2):

Install `smbclient` on your remote server

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply..I am using linux server.And my PC is windows pc..Is there any link for this connectivity..so that i can know..

Comment: If I install smbclient in my server will it wok proper without any issue.I am using cloud server (but cmbclient allow only vps and dedicative).So i need to change the server.Please double confirm that..

Comment: The error you got is `sh: smbclient: command not found` so yes, you definetly need to install it if you want to get rid of this error